# Joomla 3 Registry::loadJSON

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I'm working through the tutorial to write a component for Joomla 3. [Last complete Joomla 3 lesson](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Adding_decorations_to_the_backend) .  The part that I'm busy with is [Developing a MVC Component/Adding configuration](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Adding_configuration).  So I look at the [2.5 tutorial](http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_%28MVC%29_Component_for_Joomla!2.5_-_Part_13) but it uses a deprecated function called **Registry::loadJSON()**

Where can I find info on what to use? (I've googled, a lot, but can't find any info).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*blush* It is in the comment

```
// loadJSON is @deprecated    12.1  Use loadString passing JSON as the format instead.
//$params->loadString($this->item->params, 'JSON');
```

The only thin is that $this->item->params should be $this->params (This is also in the comments)